# How to pass a signal to a constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to pass a signal to a constructor of a class and make a connection in the constructor. I am trying something like the code shown below but it is not working. The overall goal here is so that only the employer can tell the employee to do work.

```
class Employee {
public:
    template <typename Signal>
    void Employee(QObject* sender, Signal signal) {
        connect(sender, signal, this, [this](int task) {
            doWork(task);
        });
    }

private:
    void doWork(int task) { /* do something */}
};

class Employer {
public:
    void Employer(){
        // how to pass the signal here to the constructor
        Employee emp = new Employee(this, &Employer::sendWork);
    }

signals:
    void sendWork(int task);
};
```

Comment: If the intention is for `Employee` to always be parented to `Employer`, then why not make `sender` a `Employer*` instead of `QObject*`? Then, the employee can connect all the appropriate signals from the employer instead of just one, and you don't need to pass the signal as a parameter. Also don't forget that these classes should inherit `QObject` or some subclass of that. Your implementation shows no inheritance. For signals and slots to work you also need to use the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class definition in order for the Meta-Object Compiler to set up signals and slots correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point, which is what I ended up doing as the accepted answer shows. However, I also need to pass the signal because it may be different signals for a different employee instance (which I've not shown the detail for in my minimal example). Yeah, also I didn't show the QOBject macro but I'm aware it has to be there. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a pointer to a member function of `Employer` that takes an `int` and returns `void`. You can define such a variable by:

```
void(Employer::* variable_name)(int)
```

A project that compiles would have the following file structure:

```
CMakeLists.txt
Employer.hpp
Employer.cpp
main.cpp
build/
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(main CXX)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

add_executable(main main.cpp Employer.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main Qt6::Core)
```

`Employer.hpp`

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>

class Employer;

class Employee: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Employee(Employer* sender, void(Employer::* signal)(int));
};

class Employer: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Employer();

signals:
    void sendWork(int task);
};
```

`Employer.cpp`

```
#include "Employer.hpp"

#include <QDebug>

Employee::Employee(Employer* sender, void(Employer::* signal)(int))
    : QObject(sender) // set as parent to remove this with sender
{
    connect(sender, signal, [this](int task) {
        qDebug() << task;
    });
}

Employer::Employer() {
    new Employee(this, &Employer::sendWork);
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "Employer.hpp"

int main() {
    Employer employer;
    employer.sendWork(5);
}
```

You can build it by opening a terminal in `build` and then call `cmake`:

```bash
cmake ..
cmake --build .
./main
```

The last line will execute your program. The output is `5`.

Answer (score -2):

You pass signals to constructors the same way you pass other arguments - just list them after the instance type:
Employee(QObject* sender, decltype(&Employer::sendWork) signal)

So your full constructor call would be:
Employee(this, &Employer::sendWork)

The reason your original code didn't work is that &Employer::sendWork is a function type (a pointer to a function), but Signal is a template type parameter - so you were effectively passing in a type, not a value.
Specifying the exact type you want to pass (decltype is useful here to deduce the correct type from the expression) avoids that issue.
A few other notes:

Use camelCase for method names in C++, not PascalCase
You don't need to qualify the signal with sender-> - it's implicit that signals/slots are member functions
You don't need to pass this as the sender - just pass nullptr and the connection will be invalid (which is fine if you only expect incoming signals)

So a cleaned up version would be:

```
class Employee {
public:
Employee(decltype(&Employer::sendWork) signal) {
connect(nullptr, signal, this, &Employee::doWork);
}

private:
void doWork(int task) { /* ... */ }
};

class Employer {
public:
void sendWork(int task) { /* ... */ }
};

int main() {
Employee{&Employer::sendWork};
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, and is not how Qt works.

Comment: *Use camelCase for method names in C++, not PascalCase* Why?